# Эмуляция нажатия Ctrl+C

Tags: c#, winforms

Я использую SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)"); и оно работает но не везде ,мне нужно чтобы программа копировала текст в буфер из любой другой программы

Comment: ну виндовс форма

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: не смог нормально разобраться ,типа оно то копирует но не в программах

Comment: то есть оно делает ровно тоже что и SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)");

Comment: Ну тогда я не знаю, что вам нужно. Копировать можно только из активного окна. Что такое "в программах" - известно только вам. Windows тоже программа. А программист, очевидно, человек.

Comment: ок буду играть по твоим правилам,моя программа работает в браузере ,блокноте ,дискорде ,а вот активных окнах игр она работать почему то отказывается

Comment: Вы наверное какие-нибудь Thread.Sleep там устроили и ждете что передача сообщений на заблокированном UI потоке будет работать. Но кода не видно, можно только гадать. Либо читаете буфер до того как он обновится.